# Gwt : How to not to fire a click event after focus?

Tags: events, gwt, button, onclick, focus

I've created some elements of my GUI with GWT framework. I've just one button with an simple onCLick method. And when the button gets the focus (setfocus(true)) the triogger fires a click event automatically. But I just want the button holds the focus without fire any events .
How to make it in a simple way ?

---

my code :

```
public void onModuleLoad(){
..............
    textBoxTx = new TextBox();
    textBoxTx.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
        switch(event.getNativeKeyCode()){ 
        case KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER: addTx();
    }
        }
   });
....
protected void addTx() 
    final String tx = textBoxTx.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
    textBoxTx.setFocus(true);
    if (!tx.matches("^[0-9\\.]{1,10}$")) {
        Window.alert("'" + tx + "' n'est pas valide .");
        textBoxTx.selectAll();
        return;
      }
    textBoxTx.setText("");
    param_Tx=Double.parseDouble(tx);
    if (param_An==0)
        rateFlexTable.setText(1, 2, tx);
    else
    {
    for (int i=1;i<=param_An;i++)
    rateFlexTable.setText(i, 2,tx);
    rateFlexTable.setText(param_An, 4,"");
    }
**// fire the click event of my button when I give the focus**
    **btnCalcul.setFocus(true)**
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standard `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button`, calling `setFocus(true)` on it will not activate the ClickHandlers for that button.  It may be good if you could share some code because what you describe should not happen unless you are explicitly calling `Button.click()` or the user is actually click on the button.